# Linux regmap reg_read

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, spi

There is the [regmap API](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.8.9/source/include/linux/regmap.h) in the linux kernel which provides easy access for register based devices.

My device (an ADC, which is currently not supported by the kernel itself), is command based (which means, you send a command, e.g. `0x04` to start a ADC conversion) and you get an answer back. The device will be access via SPI and is registered as such.

Similarly with the registers on the device, so you write `0x2Y`, where `Y` is the register you want to read and the next 8 bits are the values for that register, or `0x4Y` and you will get the value of that register back.

This isn't a plain register based device anymore, but IMHO this is the perfect candidate for the regmap API, because a register has fields, which have a certain start bit and size in the register itself. The regmap API helps you with its [`reg_field`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.8.9/source/include/linux/regmap.h#L1107) to access them safe and easy, which means reading, updating and writing will become less of a hassle.

---

To achieve this, I thought I simply provide the `.reg_read` and `.reg_write` callback field in the [`regmap_config` struct](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.8.9/source/include/linux/regmap.h#L375) and be good to go, **but** this doesn't work, because of [this code](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.8.9/source/drivers/base/regmap/regmap.c#L813) in the `regmap_init` function.

```
if (!bus) {
    map->reg_read  = config->reg_read;
    map->reg_write = config->reg_write;

    map->defer_caching = false;
    goto skip_format_initialization;
} else if (!bus->read || !bus->write) {
    map->reg_read = _regmap_bus_reg_read;
    map->reg_write = _regmap_bus_reg_write;
    map->reg_update_bits = bus->reg_update_bits;

    map->defer_caching = false;
    goto skip_format_initialization;
} else {
    map->reg_read  = _regmap_bus_read;
    map->reg_update_bits = bus->reg_update_bits;
}
```

The problem is, `bus` is a pointer to the spi device, which means that always the `_regmap_bus_read` callback will be used, instead of my provided `config->reg_read`.

---

What is the inteded way of achieving, what I want, e.g. providing a custom `reg_read` and `reg_write` function with a already provided bus.
Some drivers provide their own "framework" for reading and writing registers, but I want to stick to the plain regmap API.

Is it a good idea to overwrite the `reg_read` and `reg_write` after the `devm_regmap_init_spi` call? Does it introduce any unforseeable problems? Is there a workaround or something I don't see what will make my life easier?

Answer (score 0):

I somewhat solved the problem, but I'm still not sure if it's the right way.

Instead of using `devm_regmap_init_spi(spi, &config)` I now use `devm_regmap_init(&spi->dev, NULL, spi, &config)`.

I pass `NULL` as the `bus` parameter, which means the `map` fields `reg_read` and `reg_write` will be filled by the passed config.

The `spi` parameter after `NULL` is passed as the context pointer to my `reg_read`/`reg_write` functions, so I can use it there. Adjust it to any other pointer if you need it.

(I'm happy to hear other solutions)

Comment: This is not correct. Those callbacks are purely for regmap API extensions, such as AC97 codec accessors or so. In your case you simple use starnart regmap SPI in conjuction with bitfield.h APIs. There are plenty of examples in the kernel (even in *drivers/iio/adc* which supposedly is a home for your driver).

Comment: @0andriy thanks for the comment. As stated in my question, I can't use the standard regmap API, because the correct command won't be used, instead it will just send the register to the SPI bus. If you could show me one example in the kernel drivers, I might be able to answer to extract the correct way out of it.

Comment: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/gpio/gpio-pca953x.c#L392  You need to define `.max_register = 0xf`, `.read_flag_mask = BIT(6)` and `.write_flag_mask = BIT(5)`. If I am not mistaken this should work.

Comment: I see the command set is needed. So, you need to use the following mapping 0x0-0xf — registers, 0x0-0xf with BIT(4) — command. Then you define your `->write()` method where you check if ADC_CMD bit (bit 4) is set, drop it and send command, otherwise use as is. Something like that. Just read existing code (e.g. https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/net/can/m_can/tcan4x5x.c#L96), you will learn from it. As a last resort you may extend regmap API itself.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. **But** your code also does use the `devm_regmap_init` function and provides "it's own bus". I'm not entirely sure, if that's better. I can of course use that approach. But IMHO my seems more elegant? Don't know...

Comment: First example uses native I²C regmap API, second one is more customized, indeed (note nevertheless there is no NULL argument there).